# Jenkins user is missing the Overall/Read permission - Project Roles

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I know this question has been asked several times before. But I could not find a solution for my case, therefore I thought to ask the question.

I created a new user in jenkins and I need this user to see only the set of projects which follows a specific naming pattern. Therefore, I assigned that user a project role which is also a newly created one.

However when I log in using the newly created user, I get `<user> is missing the Overall/Read permission` error.

I have already tried the following methods found from the answers in other questions.

- made everything lowercase since those answers suggested doing so.
- Checked those names with the config.xml and verified
- Restarted Jenkins

Note that, I didn't made the user an admin as suggested by some answers since I need the user to not to hold an admin role.

One other thing I should mention that, I could not find questions from people who encountered the same issue while creating project roles.

Any help please?

**EDIT**

This answer seems to be relevant. As mentioned there, I also have project based matrix authorization plugin enabled.

Comment: so, use the matrix to allow user ti read/write configuration